# postgresql: create a file.sql that execute more files.sql

Tags: postgresql

I want create a file.sql that execute with:

```
> psql -f file.sql
```

in this file I want create some schemas and tables end execute other sql files:

file.sql:

```
create schema a ...
create schema b...
create table a.t1
create table b.t2...

execute /path/file2.sql;
execute /path/file3.sql;
```

Is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.

```
\i /path/file2.sql;
\i /path/file3.sql
```

Comment: with the command \i fun\on.sql;

in windows:
psql:winInstall.sql:5: fun: Permission denied

Comment: ok i resolve with \ but if i want make a file for linux and windows there is a solution or i must create 2 different files?

Comment: You can use forward-slash paths on windows too.